# How do I analyze a Java heap dump when local memory is less than the size of the dumped heap?

Tags: java, heap-dump, java-memory-leaks, jhat

I have a really big *hprof* file about **21G** which located on a remote server with **32G** memory, and I would like to understand what happened in my program. However, on my local desktop I have only **8G** memory so it's impossible to launch this file locally.

I tried

```
jhad -J-d64 -J-mx25g
```

but it failed with out of memory error on remove server.

So maybe exists other tools with may help me analyze this file?

Comment: look at eclipse MAT